# How to pass value from inherited class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

For some reasons when I try to access the public property from the inherited class, it returns 0. Here is my code. When I print `savings.AccountBalance` I get 0. What am I doing wrong? I would like to use properties from inherited class or use its variables. I don't want variables to be public though, So I will have to change them to `protected` instead of `private`.

```
class AccountTest
{
    static void Main ( string[] args )
    {
        Account account = new Account ();    //declaring account object
        SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount ();
        Console.Write ( "Enter account balance: " );
        account.AccountBalance = Convert.ToDecimal ( Console.ReadLine () );
        Console.WriteLine ( "Enter Interest rate in percentage: " );
        savings.Interest = Convert.ToInt32 ( Console.ReadLine () );
        Console.WriteLine ( $"Account Balance: {account.Balance}\nInterest rate: {savings.interest}\n" +
                           $"Savings Earned Interest: {savings.CalculateInterest()}" );
    }
}
```

Second class

```
class Account
{
    private decimal accountBalance;
    public Account () { }
    public Account ( decimal balance )
    {
        AccountBalance = balance;
    }
    public decimal AccountBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return accountBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Account balance cannot be negative number" );
            }
            else
            {
                accountBalance = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return accountBalance;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my last class. Why CalculateInterest method is returning 0?

```
class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    public double interest;
    public SavingsAccount () : base () { }
    public SavingsAccount ( decimal initialBalance ) : base ( initialBalance )
    {
        initialBalance = AccountBalance;
    }
    public SavingsAccount ( double interests )
    {
        interests = Interest;
    }
    public double Interest
    {
        get
        {
            return interest;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                interest = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Interest Cannot be Negative" );
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal CalculateInterest () => 
        Balance * Convert.ToDecimal ( interest / 100 );
}
```

This is an updated version of my previous question.

Comment: 1. getID isn't a valid property 2. Even if it was it's not initalized so empId will always be 0. 3. I think you rethink your problem because i'm struggling to understand why you want to do this

Comment: In your base class constructor for `Person` you set the local `ID` to the property `Id`. It should probably be `Id = ID` instead.

Comment: How would you pass values from an inherited class?

Comment: Your line 'ID = Id;' is the wrong way around. A typo in this post?

Comment: Your `Employee` class automatically inherits the `Id` property from `Person`. What exactly is it you're trying to do? After initializing an `Employee`, clients can access `Employee.Id`. Why not just let inheritance do the work, and get rid of all the `empId`/`getID` stuff?

Comment: @RufusL When I do that I get 0

Comment: If you remove all the `empId` and `getId` references and just have the two constructors for `Employee` that call their `base` counterparts, and then you do `var e = new Employee(3); Console.WriteLine(e.Id);`, the result will be `3`, not `0`. Can you post the code you're using where you get `0`?

Comment: @RufusL I just updated my question to the actual code I am using.

Comment: You have declared two different objects, so setting properties of one will not affect the other. Just declare one `SavingsAccount` object and do all the work on that (i.e. use `savingsAccount.AccountBalance = ...;`). Perhaps you should also read more about inheritance and how it works if this seems confusing.

Comment: @RufusL That was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues the code doesn't compile because your missing semi-colons and property is incorrect, however once that is done your Person constructor is incorrect as you have the assignment the wrong way around. Finally the getID property is not initalized so it will always be 0.

Finally getId property is redundant since you inherit from Person the Id property so it's not even needed. If you want to get employee id you call Id property.

Here is what it's suppose to look like.

```
class Person 
{
    public Person (){}
    public Person (int ID)
    {
        Id = ID;
    }
    public int Id {get; set;} 
}

class Employee: Person
   {
        public Employee():base(){}
        public Employee(int emp):base(emp){}
    }
```

Edit: OP updated this question.

Firstly I strongly recommend you go back to basics and re-read how constructors work. In your saving account class in both constructors you pass in a variable but seemingly overwrite it for no reason. I think you misunderstand how the assignment operator works. If you simply pass argument into the child class, it will assign it correctly because you call the base() constructor.

For example constructor below is valid and will assign correct balance to SavingsAccount instance

```
public SavingsAccount ( decimal initialBalance ) : base ( initialBalance ){}
```

Furthermore the constructor below doesn't make any sense, you are passing interest amount then overwriting so it will always be 0.

```
public SavingsAccount ( double interests )
{
    interests = Interest;
}
```

Instead swap around the assignment so the property gets updated with correct value you've passed in i.e `Interest = interests;`

If you want to extend this constructor further you can also mix them both up to give you saving account with interest and balance without having to use properties like this:

```
public SavingsAccount ( decimal initialBalance, double interest ) : base ( initialBalance )
{
    Interest = interest;
}
```

Secondly you are misunderstanding how inheritance works, you don't need instance of child and parent classes. If you create an instance of child class it will *inherit* the member fields and methods. Unless you need an instance of Account class for other reasons you do not need to create it. Simply creating the Saving instance is enough, this will allow you to access the methods/fields of Account class. For example the code below is sufficent

```
SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount (); //Creates SavingAccount instance
Console.Write ( "Enter account balance: " );
savings.AccountBalance = Convert.ToDecimal ( Console.ReadLine () ); //Assigns an account balance to SavingAccount instance you have created
Console.WriteLine ( "Enter Interest rate in percentage: " );
savings.Interest = Convert.ToInt32 ( Console.ReadLine () ); //Assigns an interst to SavingAccount instance you have created
Console.WriteLine ( savings.AccountBalance );
```

Comment: The only change I'd suggest is name the argument to the `Person` constructor using camelCase (`id` instead of `ID`), which is the convention for C#, and the call to the empty base constructor is redundant, since that will always get called.

Comment: I just updated my question to the actual code I am using. Can you take a look and tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You declared a Property `getId`in your `Employee` class, witch is initialized with the default value of zero. This is why `empId` will be initialized with zero too. Your `id` field is also never Initialited and never used. If you meant the `Id` property, there is no need to declare a backing field, since it's declares as an auto property, witch will result in a backing field beeing generated by the compiler.

There is also one other issue with your code. Your `Person`s constructor sets the parameter `ID` to the value of the property `Id` witch is zero and probably not what you want.

So to clean up your code, you may want to use something like this.

```
class Person 
{
    public Person (){}
    public Person (int id)
    {
        Id = id
    }

    public int Id {get;set} 
}

class Employee : Person
{
    private int empId;
    public Employee(): base(){}
    public Employee(int emp) : base(emp)
    {
        empId = Id;
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need to store `empId` in a seperate field, if its value will be the same as `Id`. Since `Employee` inherits from `Person` it will have that property too.

Comment: Where is `empId` defined?

Comment: @RufusL I changed my mind, which simplifications i made during writing the answer, so result became inconsistend.

Answer (score 0):

I think id from the Person class and empId from the Employee class are supposed to be the same thing.  If so then there is no need to have anything in the Employee class as the Person class already exposes id through the Id property.

Also you do not need constructors such as Person(int ID) if you have a constructor Person() because you can use initialization to assign id through the Id property.  And in the person class I think you don't actually want both id and Id as they refer to two different values.  I think you mean for it to be the same thing?  If so here is the code that would do what you need.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person
{
}

// code somewhere else

Employee employee = new Employee { Id = 10 };
```